# Asp.net reset fields and ConfirmCancel

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Am using master page in my asp.net application, and I want to reset the fields when I click the `Cancel` button.

I can achieve this by adding the onClientClick event as

```
OnClientClick="this.form.reset();return false;"
```

its working but, I already used this function for showing the confirm cancel popup like,

```
OnClientClick="return confirmCancel()"
```

this confirmCancel() is written in the js file called `Custom.js` and its under the folder called `Script`.

I need to show this `confirmCancel()` pop up and if I give ok it should clear the form, how can I achieve this, can anyone help me here...

this is the confirmCancel() method

```
function confirmCancel() {
var c = confirm("Confirm Cancel?");
if (c) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: add the code of **Custom.js** file or **confirmCancel()**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make

```
OnClientClick="return (confirm('Clear Form ?') && this.form.reset(),false)"
```

I make a simple test here: http://jsfiddle.net/LY3dd/4/

What I do here, by adding the `&&` the javascript first run the `confirm` and if this is return true, then is run the second part that is the reset. If the `confirm` return false, is stop there (and not clear the form).

Comment: @Shanish to avoid the post back., change it to true to allow post back with the cancel.

Comment: I have one more doubt, its not retaining the dropdown value, whose AutoPostback property is enabled....how to fix this, any idea?

Comment: @Shanish I do not follow. Can you please be more specific, after the cancel you do not won post back, but the drop down list make autopostback ? Or not change to their default ?

Comment: the above query retains all the fields even ddl(if its AutoPostback=false), but for the ddl(if its AutoPostback=true), its not retaining the default value

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about what is written in confirmCancel function, It should return true or false based on the user confirmation e.g.

```
function confirmCancel () {
var answer = confirm("Leave ?")
if (answer){
    return true;
        }
else{
    return false;
}
}
```

And modify client click function like this

```
OnClientClick="if (confirmCancel()) { this.form.reset();return true; } else {return false;}"
```

Comment: I updated my question, and ur assumption is correct, this is what I expected, thanks